# Install GeoIP package using yum on Centos issue

Tags: centos, yum, geo

I am trying to get the db files from the geo ip, but my folder `/usr/share/GeoIP` folders is always empty. When running: `yum install GeoIP`, I am getting message:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.xtom.nl
 * epel: mirror.hostnet.nl
 * extras: mirror.seedvps.com
 * updates: mirror.dataone.nl
Package GeoIP-1.5.0-14.el7.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Any clue why my folder is empty ? PS: I removed the `GeoIP folder` (with the old version of the db) and recreated it manually.

Thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the package locate file in different directory. You can check where the files are located with command:

```
rpm -ql GeoIP
```